# Create ascending series of integers by group in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create an ascending list of integers by group in pandas:

```
Group    Date
  A      2000-01-01
  A      2000-01-12
  A      2000-01-15
  A      2000-10-01
  B      2005-02-05
  B      2006-04-10
  B      2010-08-20
```

Would become this:

```
Group    Date          obs_num
  A      2000-01-01      1
  A      2000-01-12      2
  A      2000-01-15      3
  A      2000-10-01      4
  B      2005-02-05      1
  B      2006-04-10      2
  B      2010-08-20      3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do something slick with cumsum such as:

```
df['obs_num'] = 1
df['obs_num'] = df.groupby('Group')['obs_num'].cumsum()
```

My small test had this version as 6ms vs 14.8ms for Tom's solution.

Comment: I like this. Very clever!

Comment: this is what the new method cumcount in 0.13 does

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work for you. I need to check a slight detail.

Start by resetting the index. It looks like when grouping by level (on the index) the order is not preserved.

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]: 
             Date
Group            
A      2000-01-01
A      2000-01-12
A      2000-01-15
A      2000-10-01
B      2005-02-05
B      2006-04-10
B      2010-08-20

[7 rows x 1 columns]

In [32]: df = df.reset_index()
```

Now it's just a one-liner:

```
In [42]: df['obs_num'] = df.groupby('Group').transform(lambda x: np.arange(1, len(x) + 1))

In [43]: df
Out[43]: 
  Group        Date  obs_num
0     A  2000-01-01        1
1     A  2000-01-12        2
2     A  2000-01-15        3
3     A  2000-10-01        4
4     B  2005-02-05        1
5     B  2006-04-10        2
6     B  2010-08-20        3

[7 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks. Getting a ValueError though: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 22